# Spritekit bouncing angle tends to 90 degrees, why?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, angle

While testing Spritekit (on iOS) I found that in a zero gravity physicsworld, limited by the scene frame, a bouncing object's outcome angle  tends towards the normal (90 degrees) of the surface (scene frame edges) it hits. The result being it will eventually start bouncing back and forth between the left/right or up/down. If I lower restitution and/or increase lineardamping this behaviour goes away.

I can't make sense of it. Why does this happen?

This is how I define the node and body I then apply some impulse to.

```
fingerTip.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)
fingerTip.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: CGFloat(10))
fingerTip.physicsBody!.restitution = 0.95
fingerTip.physicsBody!.linearDamping = 0.0.5
self.addChild(fingerTip)
```

Comment: This is a well known problem, which has been unfixed for many years. Your code is not to blame, and all the related questions on this still go unanswered.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Is my observation of the resitution playing a role correct or is the problem present always in various degrees depending on damping and restitution?

Comment: I am not to sure exactly what the problems are, but here is my theory: If I apply a very small impulse to the ball, it does not move (like real life). However, the object only moves when given enough force. I think that because of the angle, the impulse in that direction is too small that it does not have an affect, and therefore does not bounce back. So what are the solutions? Well, you can change the ball size which should prevent this from happening.

Comment: Not sure if we are talking about the same problem here. My problem is that the bouncing in angle and the bouncing out angle does not correspond like expected and the bouncing out angle tends towards 90 degrees to the surface which eventually leads to bouncing back and forth between the same points on either side of the view.

Comment: I do know exactly what you mean, I had the same problem. It is still an unanswered question (I'm pretty sure). Your ball just gets stuck bouncing in one line, back and forth.

Comment: OK, I guess one solution is to compensate the impulse vector at impact for the wrong bouncing off angle but that's definitely a lot of work. Not fun.